# How to seperate string to other TextBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, manipulate

I am using Visual Studio, I type in the first textbox for example Name:First/age:22 but if try other name it will not work. How to manipulate the string inputted by the user. Any advise what is the use for this scenario except this substring?

```
 private void btnManipulate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string stringmanipulate = inputString.Text;
            resultName.Text = stringmanipulate.Substring(5, 5);
            resultAge.Text = stringmanipulate.Substring(15, 2);
        }
```

This is my example output

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

If I type this

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

This is the error

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: Welcome to the fun world of parsing. I suggest you use a Regular Expression.

Comment: Use more than one TextBox?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [String.Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split)

```
//stringArray[0] will be your original string up until / - "Name:blabla"
//stringArray[1] will be your original string after / - "age:22"
var stringArray = stringmanipulate.Split('/');
```

After that you can use `String.Split()` again but with the ':' character and apply the same logic